# Tracing oracle client kerberos

Tags: oracle, kerberos, mit-kerberos

how to trace oracle client for kerberos? krb5.conf for client logging section:

```
[logging] 
default = FILE:C:\tmp\krb5client.log
kdc = FILE:C:\tmp\krb5clientkdc.log
admin_server = FILE:C:\tmp\krb5clientadmsrv.log
```

all files are empty - no data at all!

Is this section (logging) of krb5.conf applies to client or to servers parts only?

Comment: What kind of "Oracle client" are you talking about - is it a Java program, a C++ program? for Oracle database, Oracle BI, Oracle ERP, Oracle Java Runtime Engine, Oracle Weblogic, etc??

Comment: In this context, oracle client is Oracle instant client 12v with sqlplus